# How to extract the Lat and Long coordinates used to create the boundaries of polygons in a shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, geometry, coordinates, xy

I have a shapefile that contains 10 polygons that represent 10 legal fishery management zones. I would like to extract the latitude and longitudinal data points used to create each polygon so that I can look at the coordinates of where crayfish pots were placed, and determine which management zones this fishing activity occurred in. When I look at the attributes table of the shapefile it only provides a single geometric value for each polygon, which appears to be the calculated size of each area/polygon. So far I have tried changing the multipoint .Shp file to a single-point .Shp file to extract the centroid data. However, this only provides a single data point in the center of each polygon. What I need is all of the coordinates that identify the complete boundary of each polygon. Can anyone tell me if this is possible and how it is done?

Comment: [Right click - Export - Save Features as](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-new-layers-from-an-existing-layer) and save as CSV with geometry as WKT.

Comment: Did you mean under the Layer Options > AS_WKT? Also, under Geometry, there are the options Automatic, Point, LineString, Polygon then GeometryCollection, No Geometry with the options Force multi-type or include z-dimension for Geometry type. What needs to be selected here? Do I just leave it as the default, Automatic?

Comment: The output looks hopeful, producing a WKT column with heaps of data which could be coordinates e.g. 6298098.3938 -3229966.8786 but aren't exactly formated as lat/longs i.e. 41.40338, 2.17403. Do you understand this?

Comment: Your data is in a projected coordinate system. Specify a geographic coordinate system (CRS parameter).

Comment: Just to clarify; when the shapefile was created (not by myself) the CRS was set to EPSG:3994 - WGS 84 / Mercator 41 - Projected. Do I need to change this somehow? Because I am setting the CRS when exporting to: Layer CRS: EPSG:3994-WGS Mercator 41 with the Geometry Type set to Automatic and the Layer Options Geometry set to AS_WKT, however, the coordinates are still exporting in the wrong format e.g. 6225154.1047 -2744169.2493

Comment: If you'll post your data you'll get a nice step-by-step with screen shots.

Comment: No you don't need to change the CRS of your data, you need to specify a different CRS when you export. A geographic CRS that uses degrees as the units instead of metres such as epsg 4326

Comment: Thank you https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2856/user2856 the Default EPSG:4326 did the trick! Just wondering https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/175638/pointdump, how do I post my data?

Comment: To post data you give a link to WeTransfer, DropBox, etc...

Comment: @AngelaRussell You can also directly compare your crayfish points to see witch polygon they are within.  Not sure how many crayfish pots you have or what format the data is in, but this is likely much more efficient than manually comparing one set of points to a set of polygons.  Guessing they are text data (csv or spreadsheet).  You could bring them into QGIS using Data source Manager > Text data > select your data > CRS = 4326.  Once you have both data sets in the same document you could intersect to assign zones to the points